# ListView header captures sliding of TabHost

Tags: android, android-webview, android-tabhost, swipe

I have a layout. First i will tell about it.
1.TabHost and below
 
2.List with Header and Footer.(Header is a `View`, that inflates a layout).

All following codings are in Fragment.

This is how i am making HeaderView:

```
View headerView;
headerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.activity_first,null, false);
```

Then am adding the headerView to listView.

```
this.list_news.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Following `activity_first.xml` is used to inflate for headerView.

**activity_first.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<include 
    android:id="@+id/content"
    layout="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Following `activity_main.xml` is used to include layout in activity_first.xml.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/net.top.ly3w"
    android:id="@+id/background_linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/photosload"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/circle_indicator"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <net.top.ly3w.viewpager.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circle_indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:padding="10dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Picture:**

[image]

So, now i will describe my problem i am getting, where `headerView` is looks like slideshow, where number of url images are loading in particular timings. It has separate touch event. It is working fine for activity. But when i using it in tabhost and when i swipe the on the slideshow the whole tab moves to the next tab. I don't want to swipe the whole tab, instead of it, i want just to swipe the next slide in headerView. So, how can i achieve it?

Setting the tab using the following code:

```
TabSpec ts1 = setupTab(new TextView(this), "?");
        TabSpec ts2 = setupTab(new TextView(this), "-");
        TabSpec ts3 = setupTab(new TextView(this), "=");
        TabSpec ts4 = setupTab(new TextView(this), "?");
        TabSpec ts5 = setupTab(new TextView(this), "?");
        TabSpec ts6 = setupTab(new TextView(this), "?");

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(ts1, NewsOneActivity.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(ts2, NewsTwoActivity.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(ts3, NewsTwoActivity.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(ts4, NewsTwoActivity.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(ts5, NewsTwoActivity.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(ts6, NewsSixActivity.class, null);

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Comment: And how do you setup those tabs?

Comment: Judging by your code, I'm assuming you also use a `ViewPager` for the tabs. If this is the case than the behavior you see it's normal as you try to swipe left/right two nested `ViewPagers`. You'll need to somehow handle the touch events for the tabs ViewPager to let the touch events pass if the touch happen in the area of the nested `ViewPager`.

Comment: @Luksprog: I have handle the touch events for the tabs ViewPager. But yet it's not working. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Can someone help me to fix it?